# IndexError: list index out of range error in python for a database

Tags: python

I am making a music database to finally fix the mess all of the music is.

my program works (Gives the correct answer) but still comes with an error, could you help me?

The code is:

```
import csv

M_TYPE = 0
M_ARTIST = 1
M_TITLE = 2
M_YEAR = 3

def read_music():
    with open('MuziekDatabaseThuis.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
        musicreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        for music in musicreader:
            #print(', '.join(music))
            if music[M_TYPE] == 'CT' and music[M_ARTIST] == 'Bob Marley & The Wailers':
                print(music)

def music_add():
    with open('MuziekDatabaseThuis.txt', 'a') as csvfile:
        musicadder = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                                quotechar='|')
        musicadder.writerow(['PC', 'Natans PC', 'Coole PC', '2014'])



def main():
    read_music()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am not planning on using music_add() right now. it was just a test.

The error is:

```
['CT', 'Bob Marley & The Wailers', 'No Woman No Cry', '1989']
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "G:\Python\Database Kast Thuis\Program.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()
  File "G:\Python\Database Kast Thuis\Program.py", line 35, in main
    read_music()
  File "G:\Python\Database Kast Thuis\Program.py", line 23, in read_music
    if music[M_TYPE] == 'CT' and music[M_ARTIST] == 'Bob Marley & The Wailers':
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I know the album doesn't exist but I just needed a placeholder.

EDIT: Code pasted here and not on pastebin

Comment: What is the format of `MuziekDatabaseThuis.txt` being read in as a CSV?

Comment: Show your code here.

Comment: one of the rows does not have at least two elements.

Comment: sudo_coffee I don't get your question, Daniel Roseman, Done.
postoronnim, I don't get what you mean?

Comment: Can someone please react? i need help desperatly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright. my math teacher found the problem. i left empty lines in the text document. I will post a error avoiding script later.

Natan

EDIT: Added Error avoiding script:

If you are going to use my script for a Database:
Add a new variable called M_LEN to the top off the code and make it how many arguments are given in the txt document.
(So in my case 4)
Then you remove the current if and the print command inside and replace with:

```
if len(music) != M_LEN:
    next(csvfile, None)
elif len(music) == M_LEN:
    if music[M_TYPE] == 'CT' and music[M_ARTIST] == 'Bob Marley and The Wailers':
        print(music)
```

And ofcourse you must replace (music) with what you have....

Natan

Comment: It seems I also had the empty line issue.